# it is not possible to install php5-cli

Tags: php

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  php7.0-cli:i386 php7.0-cli

E: Package 'php5-cli' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Which ubuntu version are u using?

Comment: I am assuming you're using Ubuntu 16.04, if that's correct, why not use php7.0-cli instead?

Comment: yes I am using Ubuntu 16.04 is php5-cli not avialable for it?

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with PHP 7.0 packaged with php7.0- prefix. PHP CLI SAPI is packaged in php7.0-cli package and provides `/usr/bin/php` command symlinked to `/usr/bin/php7.0` binary using `update-alternatives` mechanism to provide best available PHP version.

If you need PHP 5.6 or PHP 5.5 CLI you need to use `ppa:ondrej/php` and install either `php5.6-cli` or `php5.5-cli` package.  You can access the CLI binaries either by using `/usr/bin/php5.6` or `/usr/bin/php5.5` or update the default `/usr/bin/php` symlink with `update-alternatives` command.