# How can I install the dependencies for Phoronix Test Suite?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, php

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I tried installing Phoronix by downloading the .deb file from [their website](https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads) and using dpkg. I get some unmet dependencies on php5 pacakges;

```
 phoronix-test-suite depends on php-cli | php5-cli; however:
  Package php-cli is not installed.
  Package php5-cli is not installed.
 phoronix-test-suite depends on php5-cli | php-xml; however:
  Package php5-cli is not installed.
  Package php-xml is not installed.
```

I tried installing these, and I get that

```
  Package php5-cli is not available, but is referred to by another package.
  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
  However the following packages replace it:
  php7.0-cli:i386 php7.0-cli
  E: Package 'php5-cli' has no installation candidate
```

apparently this is because php5 is obsolete, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765466/it-is-not-possible-to-install-php5-cli). I read the answer but I didn't understand what they were saying that I need to do.

Can someone explain to me how to overcome this dependency issue in installing Phoronix?

Comment: I run Phoronix on a 20.04 server, but I run it directly from a git clone. I have php7.4-cli.

Comment: The file control in phoronix-test-suite_10.4.0_all.deb says `Depends: php-cli|php5-cli,php5-cli|php-xml`  .....  Please install packages with apt or gdebi to get the dependencies installed. .... Ubuntu 20.04 : php-cli will install `php7.4-cli` which *is* included in the start script  `/usr/bin/phoronix-test-suite`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @N0rbert, no it doesn't there's a difficulty with installing the dependencies that come up when I use dpkg which I explained in my original post. I'm going to try gdebi

Comment: If this simple method fails, then you have broken/messed repositories. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy php-cli php-common php-gd php-xml xz-utils` to the question body by editing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

Add the PHP ppa:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Then update and upgrade:
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt upgrade`
If you get a fix-broken-install issue, try running:
`sudo apt install --fix-broken` ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592244))

Now dpkg the `.deb` and it should be resolved!

Answer (score -1):

You should try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get install <dependency_name>`

Like this:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt-get install php-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Comment: I already tried this and it doesn't work. I've edited my question to make that more clear